# Compiling Meshlab

Tags: 11.10, compiling, install-from-source

I am trying to install Meshlab as per the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/meshlab/index.php?title=Compiling). I installed all the dependencies and followed the steps. But am having trouble with certain steps here.

- In order to successfully compile a MeshLab's plugin with external dependency you have before to compile the referred library and put it into the folder `~/devel/meshlab/src/external/lib/YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT` where `YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT` is a string related to your operating system and compiler's version.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and `gcc`, `qmake`. I do not know what is the exact value of the string I have to give for `YOUR_DEVELOPMENT_ENVIRONMENT`. I tried to go through `qmake` guide and qmakespec definitions. It said it would actually lead to a path.

As per [this link](http://vollkorn.cryptobitch.de/index.php?/archives/96-HowTo-compile-MeshLab-), for Ubuntu 10.04, he has given the value as `linux-gcc`. Can you please tell me what value I should give?

- I tried to compile the `meshlab_mini.pro`, which doesn't not need the external libraries, but got this error.

  ```
   /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ljhead
  ```

I do not know how to proceed after this. Please help me here.

```
      from-source-on-Ubuntu-Lucid-10.04.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile `meshlab_full` but I hit an error. It seams like, you have to compile the external dependencies first! -> [Meshlab](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/meshlab/index.php?title=Compiling#External_Dependencies)
(So go to meshlab/src/external/ and compile external.pro)

I tried to compile the `meshlab_mini.pro`, which doesn't need the external libraries, but got this error.

I think thats not right..

*jhead ( http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead ), absolutely required. It's needed by MeshLab main application. In order to compile it, please read in the following lines how to compile MeshLab's external libraries.*

Comment: I wasn't able to resolve this, So  just installed it from Synaptic Package Manager.